# Intersphinx Docstring Readability

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, sphinx-napoleon

Intersphinx is a very nice tool in order to put cross-references into package documentations. However, one issue is that the way these cross-references are written results in reduced legibility of the docstrings when read with `help(function)` in the terminal or `function?` in a jupyter-notebook.

Consider the following example:

```py
def time2int(ds: Series) -> Series:
    """Convert :class:`~pandas.Series` encoded as 
    :class:`~numpy.datetime64` or :class:`~numpy.timedelta64` to :class:`int`

    Parameters
    ----------
    ds: Series

    Returns
    -------
    Series
    """
```

Note that thanks to a type alias, the Parameter and Return Type actually do not require the `` :class:`~pandas. `` prefix:

```py
napoleon_type_aliases = {
    "Series" : "~pandas.Series"
}
```

Is there an easy way to achieve the same for the function description part of the docstring? Ideally, I would hope that there is a way to define a macro that reduces the amount of noise (= non-content characters) in the docstring as much as possible. If it were possible to define macro / cross-reference such that we could write `Series_` or `:Series:` or something similar instead of `` :class:`~pandas.Series` ``  and get the same formatting would already be a huge improvement.

Comment: You could remove it from the docstring and put it in narrative documentation. Otherwise, I don't know of any option that does what you want.

Comment: Similar feature request: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5456